# No valid app key, exiting

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm building an iPhone app in XCode and it was just fine untill yesterday when it started to crash with a **"No valid app key, exiting"** error message in the console. It usually crashes a few seconds after starting, every time at a different point and sometimes it doesn't crash at all.
A couple of days ago it was just fine and I haven't touched the code since.

BTW my developer provisioning profile is valid as well as the one for the iPhone. I'm running XCode 4.5 and iOS 6.

Thank you